# how to rotate one of two tables?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i have the following two tables

```
username            data_usage          cost
  -----               ------            ----
user1             50         159
user2             250        376
user3             150        225


  username      user1       user2       user3 
   -----        -----       -----       -----
data_usage           50     200      150
cost        159     376      225
```

and I want to check if the values are equals at both tables but the problem is that 
the username at first table is a column name and its the value at the second tables

so is there anyway to rotate on of this tables in oracle using PL/SQL ?
or anyother way to do it ?

the output will be like this

```
user1 has different values column name data usage 250 at first table and 200 at table2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using pivot and unpivot if database version is >= Oracle 11.2

```
WITH table1(username,data_usage,cost) AS (
SELECT 'user1', 50, 159 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'user2', 250, 376 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'user3', 150, 225 FROM dual),
table2(username,user1,user2,user3) AS (
SELECT 'data_usage', 50, 200, 150 FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'cost', 159, 376, 225 FROM dual)
---
--End of data preparation
---
select tb.username || ' has different values column name data usage '|| tb.data_usage ||' at first table and '|| ta.data_usage ||' at table2' as text
from (select *
        from table2
     unpivot (val for users in (user1 as 'user1', user2 as 'user2', user3 as 'user3'))
       pivot (min(val) for username in ('data_usage' as data_usage, 'cost' as cost))) ta
join table1 tb on (username = users)
WHERE ta.data_usage <> tb.data_usage;
```

Ouput:

```
|                                                                                   TEXT |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| user2 has different values column name data usage 250 at first table and 200 at table2 |
```

Just use this query

```
select tb.username || ' has different values column name data usage '|| tb.data_usage ||' at first table and '|| ta.data_usage ||' at table2' as text
from (select *
        from table2
     unpivot (val for users in (user1 as 'user1', user2 as 'user2', user3 as 'user3'))
       pivot (min(val) for username in ('data_usage' as data_usage, 'cost' as cost))) ta
join table1 tb on (username = users)
WHERE ta.data_usage <> tb.data_usage;
```

Replace table1 and table2 with your table names

Comment: if I have to write a select statment for each record thats would be useless coz i had around 1 million record thats just an example for what I want

Comment: Don't consider the portion above  `End of data preparation` as part of the query, this is done to avoid physical table creation at my end. Use the later part only (i.e. after the `End of data preparation`) and replace table1 and table2 with your table names.